# Datetime attribute error for timedelta in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, timedelta

I have a .txt file with a list of dictionaries, where one entry in each dictionary is a time difference in the format "datetime.timedelta(days, seconds). I am trying to find the average of all the time differences.  However, when I try to do anything with the timedelta in this format, I get the error

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'
```

For example, the following gives me the above attribute error:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
print(datetime.timedelta(0, 9780))
```

It seems like I can solve the problem by instead having the format:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
print(timedelta(0, 9780))
```

And I will get the result:

```
2:43:00
```

My question then is, is there a simple way to get python to be able to translate the datetime.timedelta(days, seconds) into the form timedelta(days, seconds)?

Comment: They are the same thing. `from datetime import datetime` just means that the second `datetime` masks the module, hence the error with `timedelta`. Just do something like `import datetime as dt` and then do `dt.datetime.strftime()` (or whatever it is you want `datetime` for) and `dt.timedelta()` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, `datetime.timedelta(days, seconds)` and `timedelta(days, seconds)` are the same thing.

Firstly, there is a module called `datetime` that contains several objects. If you do `dir(datetime)` you will see (at least in Python 2.7):

```
['MAXYEAR',
 'MINYEAR',
 '__doc__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 'date',
 'datetime',
 'datetime_CAPI',
 'time',
 'timedelta',
 'tzinfo']
```

You will note, then, that the `datetime` *module* contains two objects of interest; one *also* called `datetime` and one called `timedelta`. If you then did `dir(datetime.datetime)`, you would see:

```
['__add__',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__radd__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__rsub__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__sub__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 'astimezone',
 'combine',
 'ctime',
 'date',
 'day',
 'dst',
 'fromordinal',
 'fromtimestamp',
 'hour',
 'isocalendar',
 'isoformat',
 'isoweekday',
 'max',
 'microsecond',
 'min',
 'minute',
 'month',
 'now',
 'replace',
 'resolution',
 'second',
 'strftime',
 'strptime',
 'time',
 'timetuple',
 'timetz',
 'today',
 'toordinal',
 'tzinfo',
 'tzname',
 'utcfromtimestamp',
 'utcnow',
 'utcoffset',
 'utctimetuple',
 'weekday',
 'year']
```

There is no `timedelta` in that list.

When you did `from datetime import datetime`, you did not import the `datetime` module to use but rather imported the `datetime` *object*. All references to `datetime` therefore refer to the object, which does not have `timedelta` as an attribute/method, hence the error.

Remembering the first list, there is no difference between the following:

```
from datetime import timedelta
my_time = timedelta(0, 9780)
```

and

```
import datetime
my_time = datetime.timedelta(0, 9780)
```